# Gridview Rowcommand fires only once - Where is the error?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

My code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        BindDetails();        
}

public void BindDetails()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Designation", typeof(string)));
    dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Address", typeof(string)));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            dr["Name"] = "Ram";
            dr["Designation"] = "Manager";
            dr["Address"] = "Nerul";
        }
        else
        {
            dr["Name"] = "Shyam";
            dr["Designation"] = "CEO";
            dr["Address"] = "Vashi";
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
    grdDetails.DataSource = dt;
    grdDetails.DataBind();
}

protected void grdDetails_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Button btnEdit = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnEdit");
        //btnEdit.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference((Control)sender, "value$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()));
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference((Control)sender, "value$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()));
    }
}

protected void grdDetails_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "value")
    {
        txtName.Text = grdDetails.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Cells[0].Text;
        txtDesignation.Text = grdDetails.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Cells[1].Text;
        txtAddress.Text = grdDetails.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)].Cells[2].Text;
    }
}
```

kindly give the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i remember correctly  the `AttributeCollection` is not persisted in `ViewState`. Then you need to register the click event on every postback not only on databinding. Hence try to use `RowCreated` instead of `RowDataBound`.

```
protected void grdDetails_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Button btnEdit = (Button)e.Row.FindControl("btnEdit");
        //btnEdit.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference((Control)sender, "value$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()));
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference((Control)sender, "value$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sir, it works.
But when I click on button i.e; inside the gridview same logic is used to work as mentioned above.But I cannot find the commandname for the same.
I want to access commandname without set the properties of button control in the template field of gridview.